# Help getting started with Qt

Tags: qt, macos

I am a newby in QT and cannot even get a starting example to work. The problem is that even QtCore is not found. Think something wrong with my path or not the right version is used?

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <iostream>
#include <QtXml/QXmlSimpleReader>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QDir xmldir("/xxx/xxx");
QXmlSimpleReader xmlReader;
}
```

Example of error is:
    /Users/frank/xxx-build-desktop/../xxx/main.cpp:1: error: QtCore: No such file or directory.

Checked the path and the path to qmake is /usr/bin/qmake
If I run qmake -v this is printed:

```
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.7.0 in /Library/Frameworks
```

I am using Mac 10.6.6
Any reply will be appreciated.

Here is the project file:

```
QT       += core gui
QT       += xml
QT       += webkit
QT       += xmlpatterns

TARGET = xxx
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Results from make:

```
iMac:~/xxx/ qmake -spec macx-g++
iMac:~/xxx/ ls -ltr
total 56
-rw-rw----  1 frank  staff   349 Feb  5 16:06 xxx.pro
-rw-rw----  1 frank  staff  3875 Feb  6 12:56 main.cpp
-rw-rw----  1 frank  staff  7985 Feb  6 12:56 xxx.pro.user
-rw-rw----  1 frank  staff  8974 Feb  6 12:56 Makefile
iMac:~/xxx/ make
g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -Wall -W -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_XMLPATTERNS_LIB -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Qt4.7/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I. -I. -I/usr/include/QtCore -I. -I/usr/include/QtGui -I. -I/usr/include/QtXml -I. -I/usr/include/QtXmlPatterns -I. -I/usr/include/QtWebKit -I/usr/include -I. -F/Library/Frameworks -o main.o main.cpp
main.cpp:1:18: error: QtCore: No such file or directory
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:27: error: ‘QDir’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:27: error: expected `;' before ‘xmldir’
main.cpp:28: error: ‘xmldir’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:28: error: ‘QDir’ is not a class or namespace
main.cpp:28: error: ‘QDir’ is not a class or namespace
main.cpp:28: error: ‘QDir’ is not a class or namespace
main.cpp: At global scope:
main.cpp:25: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’
main.cpp:25: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’
main.cpp:63: warning: unused parameter ‘namespaceURI’
main.cpp:63: warning: unused parameter ‘localName’
main.cpp:63: warning: unused parameter ‘qName’
main.cpp:67: warning: unused parameter ‘namespaceURI’
main.cpp:67: warning: unused parameter ‘localName’
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
iMac:~/xxx/
```

Comment: When you run make, it should print the commands being executed (not sure if it does it on Mac though), what is the command for compiling? Does it contain correct paths to Qt include directories?

Comment: Are you referring to "/usr/bin/qmake", cause that is specified as the PATH.

Comment: @frankmoss, I was asking about what happens when you run make after qmake (the usual compilation procedure if you don't use an IDE like Qt Creator). However, I'm not even sure that there is something like make on Mac. I read there is something called XCode instead. So I can't really help here as I don't know the details of the build system used.

Comment: Sergey, updated the question with the make example. There is make, and infact QtCreator generates Makefile.

Comment: It's not Qt Creator that generates the Makefile. Qt Creator is just an IDE to integrate your tools. But I recommend learning the tools first. Since your Qt seems to set up the same way as on Linux/GCC or Windows/MinGW, the build procedure is: qmake (generate Makefile from the project file), make (build the project). Your make says that the project was build successfully the last time. But I don't even see the project file there! Try this: from the directory where the project file is, run `make distclean`, `qmake`, `make`. Then post the output, maybe we can help you then.

Comment: @frankmoss, oh, and here on SO, when replying to someone use @name notation, so the person you are replying to gets notified about your reply. Works only for the first @name in the comment though (and only the first three letters are used, so you may shorten names). But you don't have to do it when replying to the same person who wrote the answer or the question you are posting comment too - that one is going to be notified about your comment anyway (like my previous comment was to your question, so you get notified).

Comment: @SergeyTachenov have updated question with the example. See the end of question.

Comment: @frankmoss, does the /usr/include/QtCore directory exist, and if it does, does it contain the QtCore file?

Comment: @SergeyTachenov  no it doesn't exist! I found some files QtCore files in "/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/"

Comment: @frankmoss, that's strange. See my answer for a possible workaround.

Answer (score 3):

For most C++ Qt applications you write, it's not immediately obvious how to compile the application by hand. This is complicated by a number of factors:

1. The header files may be placed in different directories depending on their version
2. `moc`, the meta-object compiler, needs to be run
3. The correct version of the DLLs need to be included
4. A number of preprocessor defines need to be in place

Given all of the above, it's easiest to use a build system like `qmake`, which is native to Qt, `cmake`, or some other build system that is Qt aware.

For people new to Qt, I recommend `qmake`.

Here's the basic command line usage. Qmake provides integration with both Visual Studio and XCode, but I won't address that here:

1. Create a directory for your project
2. Write whatever files you believe you need
3. Build a project file for qmake by running `qmake` on your project as follows: `qmake -project "CONFIG+=xml"`. Since you're on mac, you might also want a `-macx` option, but I've never used it myself. At least in the past, qmake was not smart enough to pick up the XML dependency, so the "CONFIG+=xml" option adds it explicitly.
4. Create the makefiles from the project file by running qmake again: `qmake`
5. Now that you have makefiles, build the application using `make`, `nmake`, `gmake`, or the corresponding version of make for your system.

If everything has been picked up correctly by qmake, you should now be able to build your application by using make.

When you add new files to your project, they will need to be added to your project file `(*.pro)` and then `qmake` rerun without any options.

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive answer. But, why does it work on my friends computer and not mine? We have the same kind of setup. I am using Qt SDK. Even, when I open the example projects which are supposed to work out of the box, the same thing happens.

Comment: You'll need to provide some additional output or check some things. Does the QtCore directory and include file exist? Do you have permissions to access them? What is the full compile command and failure message?

Comment: Well, I would guess the QtCreator will fix the paths. I am using simply the "Build All" button in QtCreator. And I think it uses qmake judging by the Path

Answer (score 2):

`#include`s are for header files.  QtCore isn't a header, it's a directory that contains headers.

Since you're using QDir, change the first line to this:

```
#include <QtCore/QDir>
```

Comment: First, it's `#include <QDir>` as qmake adds /path/to/QtCore to the list of include directories. Second, there is the QtCore include file in the QtCore directory, it includes all the QtCore headers, which is why it isn't really recommended to use it, but still, `#include <QtCore>` should work.

Comment: That is exactly the case Sergey. Why does it not include it automatically? I have edited the question with the project file.

Answer (score 1):

It is rather strange that your /usr/include/* directores don't exist. It seems that there is something wrong with the Qt installation. I don't understand Mac specifics, but from what I've been able to find out, it looks like the `-F/Library/Frameworks` parameter that make passes to G++ should allow you to use `#include <QtCore/QtCore>` instead of just `#include <QtCore>`. In a correct Qt installation on other platforms (Windows, Linux), both forms are equally acceptable though. But judging by the fact that G++ doesn't complain about the `#include <QtXml/QXmlSimpleReader>` line, the form `#include <QtModule/ModuleHeader>` works fine in your setup, so it could be used as a workaround, provided that there are no other problems.

Note that I wouldn't recommend to include QtCore in any form, though. It includes a lot of stuff most of which is probably useless to you and it will only increase compilation time and the probability of name conflicts. Include only what you intend to use instead, like `#include <QDir>` or `#include <QtCore/QDir>` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Qt, and there's not special build requirement (PPC, 10.4, etc), I would strongly recommend that you download prepackaged [Qt SDK](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/) of your platform. And use the included IDE, [Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools), to start. That will get your feet wet quickly and less painfully.

Answer (score 0):

The variable settings you provided, which seems to be in your makefile, should actually be in a QMake file `xxx.pro`.  You then run `qmake`, which generates the `Makefile` from `xxx.pro`, and then finally can run `make`.  QMake uses variables such as `QT` and `SOURCES`, along with its knowledge of Qt and your installation, to produce a correct makefile.

Comment: The output you are referring to is from xxx.pro.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not find QtCore in /usr/include/, then this is an installation issue. In 4.7.0 I heard people having the same problem, so I guess there is a packaging problem for macs in 4.7.0.

Try to get 4.7.1 or build your own out of the sources.